# Which Tilak to be used for Lord Rama in art?

Tags: ramayana, rama, tilak

Which Tilak to be used for Lord Rama in art?  I am making a video animation. Want to confirm which tilak should be used.

Comment: Put Narayana’s tilaka. That’s what they follow in the Agamic temples in Tamil Nadu